# On power of solving Lady Tasting Tea?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, fishers-exact-test

I've learned that the solution for the [lady tasting tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea) experiment is the [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test). Is it the most powerful test for solving this problem? If there are other tests, how do they compare in power?

Also, I cannot find the formal definition of the Fisher's exact test. Is it correct to assume that, by definition, it compares the parameters of two binomial distributions under null hypothesis that both are equal?

Comment: Spelling Fisher's name correctly might help you in your researches.  The Wikipedia article gives a formal description at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test.

Comment: @whuber sorry, been spending too much time learning German :D. And yes, you are right. I have re-read it again, and the null hypothesis is indeed in the text. If anything, getting better at reading would help my research.

Comment: In the tea experiment, you have a 2x2 with fixed margins (presumably, if the lady is selecting two to be in each category - it wouldn't make sense to do anything else, since it would give her no chance to get anything else correct). Are you restricting attention to that 2x2 fixed margin case when considering 'most powerful'? Are you also considering $\alpha$ fixed at the discrete significance level that's available?

Comment: Sorry mean "everything completely correct" not "anything else"

Comment: @Glen_b (1) Yes, I am considering the 2x2 case with fixed margins. (2) I have not thought about that. I naively assumed that tests that are more powerful have lower or equal false negative rate for all p-value thresholds? Is this not the case? Are there tests that do better for some p-values and worse for other? I'm sorry, I am not an expert in the field

Comment: Under fixed margins (as Fisher also considered) we can restrict attention to a single cell - it doesn't matter which one; without loss if generality let's take the top left one. Once you specify it the rest of the table is known. So the problem is now entirely that if the distribution of the content of that cell. If we start with a null hypothesis that the lady has no ability to discern, that cell will have a hypergeometric distribution. Since you're asking about power we must consider the alternative, which would presumably be directional in this scenario...

Comment: ... (we wouldn't accept her claim if she got all the cups wrong), but is usually in either direction. This then is the context in which we would be comparing rejection rules.